# SQL query in symfony2 and doctrine2

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

i'm trying to create a SQL query in Doctrine 2 (Symfony2 Framework), and i need some help.
I have two Tables Movie and Person in relation many to many in table Movie_Person.

I want to get a Persons who plays in film. So clear SQL should look like:

```
SELECT p.* FROM Person p WHERE EXISTS 
                (SELECT m.* FROM Movie_Person m WHERE p.id = m.person_id)
```

How to write this in Symfony2 + Doctrine2 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Example taken from [the docs](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-select-examples):

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u.id 
                             FROM CmsUser u 
                            WHERE EXISTS (SELECT p.phonenumber 
                                            FROM CmsPhonenumber p 
                                           WHERE p.user = u.id)');
$ids = $query->getResult();
```

**Important note**: Remember, this is *NOT SQL*. It's *DQL*. The main difference is you operate on objects and properties as opposed to database tables and fields.